# Microsoft Project opensource alternatives

Tags: linux, open-source, cross-platform, project-management

I have been recommended to use the *Microsoft project* as a project manager in my course. But being a opensource fan and linux user what will be the best opensource alternative to this.

I have seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109579/open-source-alternative-to-microsoft-project, which suggests to use *openproj*. Openproj's last version was released 2 years back so I was thinking otherwise.

Also following the wiki [project management softwares comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software), I found out there are lot of opensource alternatives. Some software in the list with maximum features I found out are:

- [Endevour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endeavour_Software_Project_Manangement)
- [eGroupWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGroupWare) (web based)
- [Onepoint Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onepoint_Project)
- [Project.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project.net)
- [Project-Open](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project-Open)
- [Redmine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmine)
- [web2project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web2project) (web based)

Could anyone recommend what is the best (or most popular) alternative.

#### Update

Finally looking at the various project management softwares, I found out that deciding for one completely depends on your needs. The one thing that works everywhere is **Pen and Paper** as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573142/microsoft-project-opensource-alternatives/4573165#4573165) answer.

Comment: Lead web2project developer here.. we import from MS Project, have detailed Gantt Charts, have AddOns for Risk Management, and even iCal output. Our dev cycle makes quarterly releases. SourceForge just profiled us - http://sourceforge.net/blog/web2project/  But *regardless of the tool* if you don't have a process in place, you will fail. A tool doesn't give you a process.. it just gives you something to blame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your list is missing my two favorites:

- Pen and paper
- .txt files

and I don't mean this in jest! They are simple tools - but they have certain advantages to them. They have limitations in what you can track with them, and hence you only track what is important. Take it as the minimalistic approach to project management if you will.

In general, I don't tend to think you can manage software development by GANTT or PERT and resources. Most software construction is creative and implements things which have not been tried before. Hence, the problems you are to solve have a high risk of failure where you have to retry the attempt. I find that GANTT and friends are best if you have a large number of well-known low-risk tasks to accomplish.

You may not believe this to be true, but then I implore you to at least take my standpoint into consideration when you track the project in detail. Especially if and when you suddenly have to update the GANTT chart due to slips.

Comment: +1 for old-school pen & paper. You create just what you need, you don't feel bad about throwing it away when it serves no purpose any more.

Comment: @crap answers, this is what I use currently, but I have to do some project management projects for my course and I don't think this would work there.

Comment: The process which you use for project management is more important than the tool in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at RationalPlan. It has different editions based on your needs:
http://www.rationalplan.com/download.php

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openworkbench.org/ is what we are using

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Gantt.
URL: http://www.ganttproject.biz/